# Should a title be required?

Tags: bug, status-declined, title

It appears that a question can be posted without a title being supplied ([Example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130575/whats-your-geographic-information-systems-question-be-specific)).  Should this be a required field?  Did the OP actually enter that title?
Previous title to the example, "What's your geographic information systems question? Be specific."

Comment: It is the default text from the Asking a Question - some users miss this when in first posts.

Comment: I have been unable to confirm your characterization of what happened.  A title *has* to be supplied: the system won't let you post without one.  It cannot automatically check, though, that the title makes any sense.  The O.P. provided a useless title.  Recognizing that and fixing it requires community attention, regardless.

Comment: @whuber The title was changed from the default text after posting.  But shouldn't non-entry of a title react the same as not supplying tags (error barring post)?

Comment: Yes, I had consulted the edit record and saw the change.  But "no title" is different from "default title." I suppose you could suggest to the SE team that they not accept the default title, either.  As a moderator of two sites (and a somewhat active contributor to a few other sites) I have read over a hundred thousand titles and this is the first time I noticed that anybody used the default, so I doubt it's an urgent or important matter!

Answer (score 4):

It is the default text from the Asking a Question - some users miss this when in first posts.

see below

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised that it was possible to save a question in that state.  I'm sure that when I have forgotten to include a title, which I always write last, it will not let me save.  Could the asker perhaps have typed in that text?  It seems unlikely unless being mischievous and that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: There was a single time on another SE site where some Javascript / HTML magic must have gone slightly wrong; when I started typing a title, that grayed out background text suddenly turned into regular black text and so became an part of the title. (Fortunately I caught that error in good time.) Perhaps something similar happened here.